# .NET 8 SDK for 22.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, dotnet, sdk

Does anyone know if .NET/dotnet 8 SDK will be available as an official Ubuntu package for 22.04 LTS?

I know it is available for 23.10, but I have found no information regarding 22.04. I know I can install it directly from Microsoft, but I prefer an official package.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8 is available [as a Snap](https://snapcraft.io/dotnet-sdk) named (for historical reasons) .NET Core SDK. It can be installed through Ubuntu Software on Ubuntu Desktop, or through the following command:

```
$ sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic
```